# c# create csv with Tuple with more than 8 items

Tags: c#, csv, tuples

I'm currently working on a generate CSV file function, which looks like this.

```
Tuple<string, string, string, string, int, int, Tuple<int, int, int, int>> newCol;

List<Tuple<string, string, string, string, int, int, Tuple<int,int,int,int>>> tList = 
    new List<Tuple<string, string, string, string, int, int, Tuple<int, int, int, int>>>();
foreach (var item in itemList)
{
    newCol = new Tuple<string, string, string, string, int, int,Tuple<int,int,int,int>>(...);
    tList.Add(newCol);
}

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
var csv = new CsvWriter(sw);
csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
csv.WriteField("Item 1");
csv.WriteField("Item 2");
csv.WriteField("Item 3");
csv.WriteField("Item 4");
csv.WriteField("Item 5");
csv.WriteField("Item 6");
csv.WriteField("Item 7");
csv.WriteField("Item 8");
csv.WriteField("Item 9");
csv.WriteField("Item 10");
csv.NextRecord();
csv.WriteRecords(tList);

return GetBytes(sw.ToString());
```

As the code shown above, for each record has 10 items but `Tuple` only able to hold 7 single item and the rest has to new `Tuple`,

declaring the list has no problem but when trying to `csv.Writerecords(tList)`, the rest of the item other than first 7 items unable to write into the csv file,

Is there any method to fix this?

Any advice to this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just create your own class/struct with as many fields as you want?

Comment: @Moop initially the function is used for record has lesser than 7 field, but now trying to modify it to more than 7 field as requirements comes in

Comment: Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-8?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks for the TRest argument

Comment: sorry but your code is going to become your nightmare.  if i had to maintain this i would do a complete re-write.  forget `Tuple` and go with the recommendation of @Moop

Answer (score 0):

you should create a new own class or struct with fields adapted to your needs. replace Tuple with a new class

```
    public class MyClass
{
    public int myProperty {get;set;}
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
}

List<MyClass> tList = 
    new List<MyClass>();
foreach (var item in itemList)
{
    newCol = new MyClass(....);
    tList.Add(newCol);
}
```